# Is there a circuit that can multiply the voltage of wire A by the voltage of wire B?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design

Is there a general 2-input/1-output circuit that multiplies the voltage of one wire by the voltage of the other wire?

For example, Voltage of A = 3, Voltage of B = 5, output voltage is 15.

Comment: Are you looking for power electronics or signal processing electronics? Would an IC with two inputs, one output and two power supply pins be useful?

Comment: Surf the web for "4-quadrant multipliers".

Comment: Another good search term for this type of circuit is a Gilbert Cell Mixer.

Comment: Gilbert multiplier cell perhaps?

Comment: http://www.logosfoundation.org/instrum_gwr/chi/AD633.pdf

Comment: I believe the question I am asking is probably most associated with signal processing.  EE newb here.  What is an 'IC'...'integrated circuit'?  Thanks.

Comment: Not possible, but you could multiply two voltages and divide by another. If you just multiply two voltages, you don't get a voltage, you get something with a unit of volts-squared.

Comment: @C Shreve: Yes, IC means "Integrated Circuit". Signal processing is a very wide term. RF signal processing? Analog computing? ...can be quite different

Comment: @Curd Signal processing as opposed to power electronics, if you read the comment s/he was replying to.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities, mainly depending on required accuracy and speed (signal frequency)

- dual gate MOSFETs (e.g. BF961)
- mixer ICs e.g. NE612
- precision analog multiplier ICs e.g. AD633, MPY534
- log-add-antilog OpAmp circuits (i.e. calculate logarithms of both inputs signals, add them and calculate anti-log (exponential function) of sum). The log and antilog functions can be accomplished by OpAmp circuits that exploit the exponential I-V characteristic of semiconductor diodes.

The first two solutions are good for RF and when scaling is not important (e.g. RF mixing).
The latter two are good when scale is important (e.g. in analog computer).

For special cases when one of the input signals takes only values 0, 1 or 1, -1 you can use analog switches.

Comment: I assume by "scaling" you mean scaling the size of parts down. Then why would a dual-gate MOSFET be bad for scaling? I imagine that could get miniscule

Comment: With "scaling important" I meant that it is important that 1.0 means some exact voltage value. For mixing applications this is most of the time not the case, i.e. it doesn't matter if the result was multiplied by another constant factor (of course within some limits), as long as it is really constant.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest approach, you can use a **variable-gain** or v**oltage-controlled amplifier**.

Furthur as mentioned by Jack B in above comment, you can select an IC for [analog multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_multiplier) depending on the use in power electronics or signal processing electronics.